# Making dynamic library with ***.dylib on Mac OSX and Juce

Tags: c++, xcode, dynamic-linking, juce

`[Juce][1]` is the framework for Audio/Media application

It created the `XCode` project linking with `Juce` library.

I start from making test dynamic library.

I exported project to Xcode from Juce and added `source.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int helloJuce(){
   cout<<"Hello,From Juce!"<<endl;
   return 1;
}
```

Now `NewProject.dylib` is compiled.

And confirmed that entry point is registered.

```
$nm NewProject.dylib |grep hello
00000000000021b0 t __Z9helloJucev
```

in `testJuce.cpp`

#include

```
int helloJuce();
int main() {
    helloJuce();
    std::cout << "Test Finish!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

then, try to compile

```
$ g++ -o testJuce testJuce.cpp -L ./ -lNewProject
ld: library not found for -lNewProject
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I tested these patterns, but in vain.

```
cp NewProject.dylib libNewProject.dylib
cp NewProject.dylib libNewProject.so
```

In generally speaking, lib***.so style is common for dylib??

Does anyone help me?

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: You need `libNewProject.dylib` if you want to use `-lNewProject`

Comment: I see. So I changed the name to `libNewProject.dylib` and `libNewProject.so` but in vain.

Comment: I don't think you can have a space in `-L ./` so just `-L.` (assuming `libNewProject.dylib` is in the current directory)

Comment: I tried `g++ -o testJuce testJuce.cpp -L. -lNewProject` but same error occurs. There are both `libNewProject.so` `libNewProject.dylib`

Comment: does the architecture of your dylib match the architecture g++ is using?